# What is wrong with this javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
   var usr = 'charliesheen';

   function changeusr()
   {
      usr = document.getElementById("usrText").value;
      updatetwitter();
   }

   var twitter;
   newtwitter();

   function updatetwitter()
   {
      twitter.render().setUser(usr).start();
   }

   function newtwitter()
   {
     twitter =
     new TWTR.Widget({
       version: 2,
       type: 'profile',
       rpp: 4,
       interval: 6000,
       width: 200,
       height: 300,
       theme: {
         shell: {
         background: '#ffffff',
         color: '#367542'
       },
       tweets: {
          background: '#e3dfe3',
          color: '#000000',
          links: '#110af5'
       }
     },
     features: {
        scrollbar: false,
        loop: false,
        live: false,
        hashtags: true,
        timestamp: true,
        avatars: false,
        behavior: 'all'
      }
    }).render().setUser(usr).start();
}
</script>
<br/>
Change user:
<input name="usrText"/>
<button onclick="changeusr()">Go</button>
```

The results I see are: It loads fine. When I enter a new username and click "go" it may or may not reload the twitter widget, and the link "join the conversation" points to the correct url. I'd like it to reload the url with the new user entered. I'm a complete javascript noob. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you create this on jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: @Michael Haren works the same in jsfiddle...

Comment: Right...can you share it so I don't have to create it myself?

Comment: @Michael Haren http://jsfiddle.net/roviuser/aH7sY/ try that... not sure if it'll work. the jsfiddle "share" drop down doesn't work. maybe it's because i'm in IE7

Comment: @roviuser - I updated my answer. If you have the "live" feature set to "true", it seems to work a little better, but I have not been able to get it to re-draw the header.

Comment: ah! I found the code that re-draws the header. It won't do it if it thinks it has already drawn it for "profile" type views, so you have to clear out its internal cache. (Pretty lame.)

Comment: Here's your problem: var usr = 'charliesheen' LOL Charlie Sheen screws everything up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input needs an id:

```
<input id='usrText' name="usrText"/>
```

Internet Explorer will return elements by *name* from "getElementById()", but that is simply legacy broken behavior and it's not imitated by other browsers.

*edit* — an update:

There doesn't appear to be much documentation for that widget thing.  Things work somewhat better if you set the "live" feature to `true`.  Also, when you update the user, you have to zap an internal variable on the widget:

```
function updatetwitter()
{
  twitter._profileImage = null;
  twitter.setUser(usr).render().start();
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/hvxdD/) is the jsfiddle if you'd like to see it.

Comment: While this may be true, this isn't the problem. I am successfully getting the text from the box. the problem is with re-rendering the widget.

Comment: I beg to differ - if the input doesn't have an "id" value, then (except in IE) the call to "getElementById()" will return `null`.

Comment: I edited the comment to say "successfully" instead of "correctly" - while it may not be correct, I AM getting the text from it, and the problem is with re-rendering the widget. You can see it in action here: somewhatbiased.blogspot.com - you can tell that I am getting the text, because while most of the widget fails to load, the link at the bottom of the widget that says "join in on the conversation" points to the text entered...

Comment: On that page, your `<input>` element **does** have an "id" value :-)

Comment: ah - well the problem is clearly inside that Twitter widget thing; it's like it works by calling "document.write" or something.

Comment: your edit seems to give me the best performance I've seen, but still not ideal.

Comment: I agree - I don't have much (well, any) experience with tweaking the Twitter API.  It looked to me as if doing what your page does -- which seems perfectly reasonable to me -- was really something they (the Twitter people) planned for.